# Variable undefined, (JQuery Plugin Development)

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-plugins, undefined

I am working on creating my first jQuery based plugin but I am stuck at an issue.

I receive an error stating var minHeight is undefined when I am trying to console.log it.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.something = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            selector: '.selector',
            minHeight: defaults.selector.height(),
            speed: 200
        }
        console.log(defaults.minHeight);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, but the way you are currently trying has some problems. You are attempting to set an object's property (`defaults.selector`) before the object itself (`defaults`) is defined.

In order to get it done, the simplest way is to pull `minHeight`'s definition to other line. Also you might wanna take a look at jQuery's `$.extend`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.something = function (options) {
       var defaults = {
            selector: '.selector',
            speed: 200
       }
       defaults.minHeight = $(defaults.selector).height();
       console.log(defaults.minHeight);

       // extend() will set the values of 'options' that are empty with default's
       var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
       // options.minHeight will be the height of '.selector' if no options are
       // given, or 'minHeight' if one is given as parameter
       console.log(options.minHeight);
    };
})(jQuery);

// testing code so you get what I mean
$().something({minHeight: 10});
$().something();
```

See [the code above in action](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/jywxK/1/) (open the console).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your help. It was exactly what I was looking for and it fixed my issue completely! 

I actually created my first slide toggle plugin, you can see it here:
https://github.com/Shivambh28/ezToggle

Thanks again for all your help!